# Limit work author field in reports only to current user

Tags: report, youtrack, time-tracking

Currently all developers in project can create report where all work authors are listed.

Can work authors field in report be limited only to current user, so developer can only see his own spent time?

Answer (score 0):

You can [revoke](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Create-and-Edit-Roles.html#editing_existing_roles) the 'Read User Basic' and Read User Full' permissions from the role assigned to the users, then they won't see other users in the report's dropdown. You should note that in this case, these users won't see other users in other places as well, e.g., they won't be able to mention users or search issues assigned to speciifc users.

Comment: Revoking 'Read User Basic' permission indeed removes list of users from 'work authors' dropdown, but id does not prevent user to see time spent by others. Concept of 'My Own  work' doesn't seem to exist in youtrack.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not too late and this question is still relevant. But under Role permissions inside the YouTrack system, you can add/remove permissions to "Create Not Own Work Item" and "Update Not Own Work Item" and this will add/remove an option for the given role to add time spent for others than themselves.

[image]